# While installing BeautifulSoup in Python on my Mac, I am facing this issue. I have already updated the setup tools still the issue persists

Tags: python

```
Gaurangs-MacBook-Air:Python_Practice gaurang$ pip3 install BeautifulSoup
Collecting BeautifulSoup
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/1e/ee/295988deca1a5a7accd783d0dfe14524867e31abb05b6c0eeceee49c759d/BeautifulSoup-3.2.1.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/private/var/folders/zc/0dyk58m96f7f4h_5dycqsbw80000gn/T/pip-install-iwn33wod/BeautifulSoup/setup.py", line 22
        print "Unit tests have failed!"
                                      ^
    SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print("Unit tests have failed!")?

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/zc/0dyk58m96f7f4h_5dycqsbw80000gn/T/pip-install-iwn33wod/BeautifulSoup/
```

Answer (score 3):

`bs4` is for python3 and `BeautifulSoup` is for python2.
Try `pip install bs4`

(I encountered the same problem just now and found the answer here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/48884381/5400329)